# MySQL - Return generated AUTO_INCREMENT value on INSERT

Tags: php, mysql

Hopefully an easy one - I can't work out a robust solution.

I'm building a cart mechanism which generates a id_cart AUTO_INCREMENT Primary Key. The cart item has another table with cart product variables like size. I want to attribute the same id_cart in the size table.

```
CREATE TABLE
-> id_size_cart NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
-> id_cart //THIS WILL BE THE AI value from the product cart
-> size_name
```

I've seen SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID().

How solid will this be to ensure it's the last inserted ID? Don't want customers getting the wrong size!

__ *EDIT* ___

Thank you for the input. Still, I'm having trouble. See actual code below;

```
//add product to cart table
$addtocart_sql = "INSERT INTO store_cart (id_cart, id_session) VALUES ('', '".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]."')";
$addtocart_res = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $addtocart_sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect));

$last_row_id = mysqli_query($dbConnect, "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()") or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect));

echo 'INSERT worked!<br/>';
echo $last_row_id;
```

Error shows as

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /websites/LinuxPackage05/4v/35/xy/4v35xy-55415.webfusion-hosting.co.uk/public_html/noff-group.com/dev/add_to_cart.php on line 27

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which one is line 27? Also, this is a PHP syntax error. I don't think it is directly related to the `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()` part. (BTW: there's a [`mysqli_insert_id()` function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php))

Answer (score 8):

From [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-unique-id.html):

> For `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, the most recently generated ID is maintained in the server on a per-connection basis. It is not changed by another
>   client. It is not even changed if you update another `AUTO_INCREMENT`
>   column with a nonmagic value (that is, a value that is not `NULL` and
>   not `0`). Using `LAST_INSERT_ID()` and `AUTO_INCREMENT` columns
>   simultaneously from multiple clients is perfectly valid. Each client
>   will receive the last inserted ID for the last statement *that* client
>   executed.

Comment: Well OK - guess that answers my question. Thanks @jensgram.

Comment: Also, I think the performance is about the same, but you may find it more convenient to use the built-in PHP function `mysql_insert_id`. That might make it easier/cleaner to store it in a PHP variable, but I think the performance is about the same.

Comment: Note that this statement is mostly true i.e. as long as you're not having multiple thread inserting using the same connection.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using InnoDB as the table type, then you'll be able to make absolutely certain you get the correct id with by simply wrapping the whole thing in a transaction.

MyISAM doesn't have transactions, but it's behaviour when getting the last insert ID is based on the connection. If several connections are open simultaneously and they all insert into the same table, each connection will get back the ID for the record they inserted.  It's less robust than the true transaction support innoDB offers but it is still unlikely that any one user will get the wrong ID.

Answer (score 0):

I have read somewhere, I can be absolutely certain of that and the source where I read it, that if you want to be dead sure **DON'T** rely on `LAST_INSERT_ID`. Use the same parameters that you used to insert the record to select the newly created record and get its id. It has something to do with mysql's implementation and threading etc.

That said, I've never seen such an implementation, I don't use that method either. However, it helps to keep this in mind.

Comment: There's no specific row identifier for the row just inserted - it is a cart so only PHPSESSID and NOW() are used with product variables. CAn think how else to identify the row if executing a SELECT query?

Comment: Like I mentioned, if you don't use the same connection request for multiple connections and if you're not having the connection object between threads, you should be safe. Even my app is implemented with these restrictions in mind. Just helps to keep these limitations in mind.

Answer (score 0):

My syntax was off a little - see the code below returning a correct LAST ID.

```
//add product to cart table
$addtocart_sql = "INSERT INTO store_cart (id_cart, id_session) VALUES ('', '".$_COOKIE["PHPSESSID"]."')";
$addtocart_res = mysqli_query($dbConnect, $addtocart_sql) or die(mysqli_error($dbConnect));

// REQUIRED 'i' + '$dbConnect' for MYSQLI function
echo 'INSERT worked!<br/>';
echo mysqli_insert_id($dbConnect);
```

Thanks for all the help - again!