# How can I query for a primary key immediately after inserting a record?

Tags: php, mysql

Using two tables in my database and splitting one HTML form's data into two different queries, I've run into an issue identifying the primary key from the first query for use as a foreign key in the second query. Here is what I'm talking about in pseudocode:

```
$FormData1, $FormData2, ... INSERT INTO table1 //primary key is auto-generated int
$key = SELECT primaryKey FROM table1 WHERE *** Uh-oh!
$otherFormData1, $otherFormData2, $key ... INSERT INTO table2
```

Given that the system needs to be designed so that concurrent transactions can occur, how do I solve this problem? If I knew it was only ever going to be run one instance at a time then I could just query for the last record added, but I don't feel like that is a very 'tidy' (or even safe) solution to my problem.

Comment: See LAST_INSERT_ID. It's session-specific

Comment: you're asking how to do X, when what you want is Y. If you want the row id for the thing you just inserted, ask that instead of asking how to get it through a query. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: Check Out [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896447/mysql-return-generated-auto-increment-value-on-insert) in the Same vein as Explosion pill's answer

Comment: That's great. Thanks for taking the time to look at my problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can query for `LAST_INSERT_ID()`, but there are the `mysqli::insert_id` and `PDO::lastInsertId` methods that you can use.  Note that these are per *connection*, so even if you have many inserts that take place from separate requests simultaneously it is safe to query.

Comment: Great! I'll do some reading and try it out. Thanks so much for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Brilliant, this confirms for me what you have already said. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0):

mysql and mysqli after firing an insert-sql have an $insert_id of the record that has just been inserted - you do not need to query your db.
You could use this:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2) VALUES ("aaa", "bbb")';
$mysqli = new mysqli();
$mysqli->query($sql);
$pKey = $mysqli->insert_id;
```

and now your $pKey has a value of id of the row that you just inserted.

(see here for more: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php)