# MYSQL - Statement to insert into 2 different tables

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a form to submit to a MYSQL database.
In my database, I have 2 tables, `Subscribers` and `Category_id`. The table structures are as follows:

**Subscribers**

```
subscriber_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
name VARCHAR(30),
email VARCHAR(30),
phone INT,PRIMARY KEY (id))
```

**Category_id**

```
category_id INT,
subscriber_id INT
```

I want to insert a new row into Subscribers. I done it using the statement below.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email, phone)
VALUES
('$_POST[name]','$_POST[email]','$_POST[phone]')";
```

And at the same time, I also want to insert a new row in Category_id, where `Subscribers.subscriber_id = Category_id.subscriber_id` // For the 'same' record

How do I write the statement for this?

Comment: I assume subscriber id is auto generated?

Comment: Be sure to escape your data, by the way.

Comment: Look at this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896447/mysql-return-generated-auto-increment-value-on-insert

Comment: your db design is not correct you should first correct your db design dude

Answer (score 0):

Your database design is not correct what you need to do is to have two tables `Subscriber` and `Category` like this:

**Subscriber => Table**

```
SubscriberID PK Auto Increment
Name
Email
Phone
CategoryID FK references Category(CategoryID)
```

**Category=> Table**

```
CategoryID PK Auto Increment
CategoryName
```

Here You can populate multiple categories and within each category you can have multiple subscribers. So when ever you want to insert a new subscriber you have to determine to which category you want to insert a subscriber and then accordingly fill `subscriber` table leaving `category` table untouched. By doing so you can always get subscriber per category just using `where` clause on subscriber table. It is the right way of doing it from Database Design Perspective.

P.S with this design you won't have to insert two records per subscriber.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are doing with your Category_id table. It looks like a many-to-many table between your Subscribers table and an unmentioned table, probably named Categories. Is this correct?

Anyway, here is a solution, given what I think you are asking:

```
# set up your connection (often set up globally, just like the old style):
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=my_db_name', $user, $pass);

$dbh->beginTransaction();

$query = "INSERT INTO subscribers (name, email, phone)
          VALUES (:NAME, :EMAIL, :PHONE);";

$dbh->prepare($query);
$dbh->bindValue('NAME', $_POST['name']);
$dbh->bindvalue('EMAIL', $_POST['email']);
$dbh->bindValue('PHONE', $_POST['phone']);
$dbh->execute();

$subscriber_id = $dbh->lastInsertId();

$query = "INSERT INTO category_id (subscriber_id, category_id)
          VALUES (:SUBSCRIBER_ID, :CATEGORY_ID)

$dbh->prepare($query);
$dbh->bindValue('SUBSCRIBER_ID', $subscriber_id);
$dbh->bindValue('CATEGORY_ID', $value_from_elsewhere); // Determined earlier.
$dbh->execute();

$dbh->commit();
```

I converted your query into a PDO-style query. Putting variables from POST directly into a SQL query string can leave you open to SQL-injection attacks.

Check out this page, or anything on how to use PDO style queries in PHP:
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/

Comment: I tried your code, but it displays an error message "Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::bindValue() in... line where bindValue appear". Is something missing?

Comment: You need to have it installed, though I believe it is by default. Here is where you can find some info about that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.setup.php

Comment: I also added the connection string at the top of the example code.